# Android/Eclipse: Error in building a project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I was trying to open Android project with these features:
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="18"

But I got an error dialog saying:
 ('Building workspace' has encountered a problem errors occurred during the build)

I'm running Eclipse on Windows 7 with the following versions of things installed

Eclipse - 4.4.2

Android Development Tools - Version: 23.0.6.1720515

Android SDK - 23.0.5

I know the problem might be in dependices or because I have mismatching in jar files between the project and appcomact library. I tried many things but did not work.

Need help please.

Answer (score 0):

try use android studio

change android:targetSdkVersion="18" to android:targetSdkVersion="22"

Comment: I changed it to android:targetSdkVersion="22", but still is not working.